# Stub ApplicationController Class Method With Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd

How would I stub the `set_headers` class method below in Rspec?

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def self.set_headers(name) 
     after_filter do
       object = instance_variable_get("@#{name}")
       headers['fancy'] = object.fancy_header
     end
  end

end
```

**regular_controller.rb**

```
class RegularController < ApplicationController
  set_headers :regular

  def index
    # do regular stuff
  end
end
```

I have tried the following below and it does not work.

**regular_controller_spec.rb**

```
describe RegularController do
  before(:each) do
    ApplicationController.any_instance.stub(:set_headers).and_return({this: 'params'})
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just tested this quickly, and found that this should work:

```
controller.class.stub(:set_headers).and_return({this: 'params'})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here:

- `set_headers` is called when `RegularController` is defined.  This happens long before the spec runs, so stubbing the `set_headers` method will have no affect.
- In your `RegularController` class definition, the receiver of `set_headers` is `RegularController` (since `self` within a class definition is the class object itself). Your attempted stub is stubbing `set_headers` on any instance of `ApplicationController`, but it is not an instance method of `ApplicationController`.

I can't really recommend how to achieve what you're trying to do because it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I updated `self.set_headers` so you can better see what I am trying to accomplish. Thx

Comment: It's still not clear to me why you want to stub this method.  Stubbing a method only has an effect if the method is called during the execution of an example.  `set_headers` is never called during any example because it is called when the class is defined. Stubbing it doesn't make any sense.